# Spanish Guitar lessons online

Tags: classical-guitar

Where can I find reliable, good instructional material about the Spanish guitar online? I'm just not able to find reliable instructors, and I think I'll be a better and faster learner through online instruction. There are bits and pieces on YouTube and on many sites, but as a formal step by step lesson plan - none that I have seen so far. I'm also new to any musical instrument.

Answer (score 1):

The Carcassi Classical Guitar Method is a long-time bible for classical guitar instruction. It talks about playing technique and fingering. The exercises are quite musical for only being beginning playing, so it should keep you inspired until you are ready for more difficulty. There are sites that have this in pdf format for free but you can also buy from Amazon [http://www.amazon.com/Mel-Bay-Presents-Complete-Carcassi/dp/0871663783/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0871663783)

This book requires that you to learn to sight-read music. It might be a pain at first, but don't under-estimate how powerful this ability will be for you in the future. When your friends who have been playing for a decade can play a couple dozen songs and you can play thousands because you can sight-read you will appreciate the little extra effort it took to get there.

As for video lessons online, I haven't had any luck. All I see is the instructor playing songs, but no really usable instruction. I can figure out how to play the songs myself, but I want to know the intricacies of how I should make a chord transition or pluck a series of notes so it sounds more smooth and melodic. I haven't seen any of that online.